# How to correctly order calls using Vue/Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have some skeleton code below which demonstrates an issue I'm having with forcing the correct order of calls. The order that I want is:

- A user triggers Foo.vue's someLocalMethod().

  - A flag is set so that Bar will become aware that a change has been made.
- The flag will trigger Bar.vues's watcher to go ahead and do some work.

  - When the work is complete it will unset the flag
- Foo.vue's someLocalMethod() will become aware that the flag was unset and continue on with its work

I should mention that both Bar and Foo are doing work that changes the store, so the files are related (instead of solely using the store as a flag between both files).

I'm assuming there's a much better/cleaner way to approach what I'm doing, but I can't quite put my finger on it.  Code is shown below.

Bar.vue

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('store', ['getSomeFlag']),
},
methods: {
  ...mapMutations('store', ['setSomeFlag']),
},
watch: {
  getSomeFlag(newValue) {
    if (newValue === true) {
      console.log('Flag is set. Going to do work');
      doWorkRelevantToBarPage();
      setSomeFlag(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Foo.vue

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions('store', ['someStoreCall']),
  ...mapMutations('store', ['setSomeFlag']),

  someLocalMethod(someData) {
    this.setSomeFlag(true);
    // somehow wait until Bar.vue's watcher becomes aware of it and completes it's own work
    this.someStoreCall(someData);      
  }
},
```

store.js

```
state: {
  someFlag: false,
  data: { 
    // Can be tons of nested structures, properties, etc
  },
},
getters: {
  getSomeFlag: (state) => state.someFlag,
},
mutations: {
  setSomeFlag(state, value) {
    state.someFlag = value;
  },
},
actions: {
  async someStoreCall({dispatch, commit, state}, data) {
    console.log('In someStoreCall');
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an event bus for this use case:

1. in your **Foo** component's `LocalMethod` you emit an event (e.g. called "**FooChanged**") on the bus
2. the event handler in **Bar** component (subscribed to "**FooChanged**" events) will do its work and then emit another event (e.g. called "**BarFinished**") on the bus
3. the event handler in your **Foo** component (subscribed to "**BarFinished**" event) will continue with the next step in your flow

Something like this:

eventBus.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
export default new Vue();
```

Foo.vue

```js
import events from "eventBus";

export default
{
  created()
  {
    events.$on("BarFinished", this.onBarFinished);
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    events.$off("BarFinished", this.onBarFinished);
  },
  methods:
  {
    LocalMethod()
    {
      ....
      events.$emit("FooChanged", param1, param2);
    },
    onBarFinished(param1)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Bar.vue

```js
import events from "eventBus";

export default
{
  created()
  {
    events.$on("FooChanged", this.onFooChanged);
  },
  beforeDestroy()
  {
    events.$off("FooChanged", this.onFooChanged);
  },
  methods:
  {
    onFooChanged(param1, param2)
    {
      ...
      events.$emit("BarFinished", param1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a better way to go. I'm gonna leave this question open a bit longer to see if any other answers come up. Thanks!

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 Event buses are a good solution for smaller applications but if you want to create a big/scalable application with vue.js it is better to use vuex

Comment: @MrClottom, how would you do that in vuex using the example above?

Answer (score 1):

## Simple solution

The problem is `Foo.vue` is essentially trying to run the `doWorkRelevantToBarPage` method in `Bar.vue` which is probably done easiest using an event bus as suggested in another response **but** using an event bus is not a good idea if you want to create larger/scalable applications with vue.js

## The problem lies in the approach

With `doWorkRelevantToBarPage` I assume you most likely want to change some state stored in `Bar.vue` or run some other methods that do so. Now that you have this method you want to run it from `Foo.vue` but this seems like the wrong approach (especially if you want to use vuex), you see you are essentially trying to change the state of a component externally which mostly isn't a good idea.

## Using Vuex

The following steps will summarize what you can do to adapt your code to use vuex

1. Move any state that `Foo.vue` needs to change externally to the store.
2. Create mutations and getters for the states you placed in the store
3. Hook up the getters to your `Bar.vue` component
4. Create an action that commits the necessary mutations as shown here (choose a more descriptive name):

```js
updateBarData({commit, dispatch}, ...args) {
  commit('mutation1')
  commit('mutation2')
  commit('mutation3')
  dispatch('action1')
  dispatch('action2')
  // ... other logic
}
```

5. Add the action to `Foo.vue`

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions('store', ['someStoreCall', 'updateBarData']),
  someLocalMethod(someData) {
    this.updateBarData()
    this.someStoreCall(someData)
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.